# work related training uk visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

i am going on a work related trip to uk to attend a training and i was wondering about the letter from my employ who will be dealing with all the payments and expenses, in the appendix it says  :

"any business activities, e.g. letter from your employer outlining the reason for your visit, who you will be meeting and details of any payment/expenses"

they already mentioned everything but the expenses ,should they mention the cost of the training i am attending, the hotel , plan tickets and my pocket money ?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the letter should mention all of the costs of the trip which your employer is paying, including the specific amounts (in GBP if possible). This should include at least airfare, hotel, and any per diem (the daily expenses your employer reimburses), if your employer is paying these.

The visa application will separately ask how much you are personally spending on the trip. For that amount you should answer only that amount which your employer is not paying or reimbursing (which is usually zero, but might be more than zero if you e.g. want to do some shopping or tourism also).